# DRF HawkREST authentication failed with postman

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, postman

Im using this library: https://hawkrest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**In my `settings.py`:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'hawkrest.HawkAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}

HAWK_CREDENTIALS = {
    'script-user': {
        'id': 'script-user',
        'key': 'aabbcc',
        'algorithm': 'sha256'
    },
}
```

**In postman:**
[image]

**In console output:**

```
access denied: MisComputedContentHash: Our hash b'l0mKQ9ZG6Df44jdvH1FthWGvtKN93umZdmQCqd7YcgI=' (sha256) did not match theirs
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica latest one. 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

HawkREST only supports Django 1.11 through 1.8 and its [github](https://github.com/kumar303/hawkrest) hasn't been updated in over 2 years, so it is likely that it won't work at all in your version.

Comment: i think this is not the case, I think postman is missing hash key-value in the Authorization header, not sure how to add. I ticked "Include payload hash" but it's not adding anything